# Fine is incrementing everytime when i reload page in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to add function of fine, which is user selects return date when he request book and if date exceeds return date then user gets a fine. But problem is everytime i reload page, fine automatically increases
Here is my controller code:

```
def index
@ownerships = current_user.ownerships
@ownerships.each do |ownership|
  ownership = Ownership.find(ownership.id)
  if Time.now >= ownership.return_date
    ownership.update(fine: ownership.fine +  100))
  else
    ownership.update(fine: 0)
  end
end
```

end

Comment: Can you explain the fine logic that you are trying to implement? How much fine do you want to charge and how is it calculated? Is it 100 per 24h or is the fine rate increasing every 24h? Maybe give some examples.

Comment: i want to increase 100 per day

Comment: In that case you should run your code once a day instead of once per page request. And it doesn't belong into the controller at all.

Comment: well that's great. And can you please guide me where does this belongs

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing what you've asked of it. Every time you go to the index page it will run that code, updating `fine` each time.

This line is continually adding to the previous `fine` value:

```
ownership.update(fine: ownership.fine + (total_days * 100))
```

So you are adding `total_days * 100` to the already existing `fine` each time you refresh.

Maybe you need to add a check, e.g. if a fine has already been added don't update it:

```
if Time.now >= ownership.return_date && ownership.fine.zero?
  today = Time.now
  ...
```

TBH though, I wouldn't store this kind of logic in the controller. It probably belongs on the model, or perhaps in a service class called from the controller.

Just a side note, this code is unnecessary:

```
@ownerships = current_user.ownerships
Ownership.all.each do |ownership|
  ownership = Ownership.find(ownership.id)
```

You're fetching all the current_user's `ownerships` and then fetching them again one by one. The code is the equivalent of

```
  @ownerships = current_user.ownerships
  @ownerships.each do |ownership|
```

Hope that's useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just edited my code, but problem is still it changes value on every refresh

Comment: Ah, well because my suggestion will actually toggle between zero and a value each time. You need to record some kind of state (e.g. a 'fine_applied' boolean) or remove that `else` clause (which is probably setting the value back to zero every second call).